# Searching for characters instead of words SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

Hello i am building a code and i am working with structures. I want to setup the search on the view. Here is what i have so far and what I’m trying to do

```
struct subCategory {
    var subCategoryName = String()
    var subCategoryDesc = String()
    var subImageId = String()
    var subType = String()
    var subLinkType = String()
    var subCatImageUrl = String()
    var subCatId = String()
}

var subCatContent = subCategory()
var subCatArray = [subCategory]()
var filteredsub = [subCategory]()
```

This is my view controller

```
self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I got it work. What i need is to search for characters instead of the entire work. So if I’m searching for TOUR once i type T or TO i want it to show up how would i do that?

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    self.filteredsub.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    filteredsub = subCatArray.filter{
        $0.subCategoryName == searchController.searchBar.text!
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

No i want to search in a list of stuff. I have it working so if TOUR is in the list it finds that but i want it to also give me a result if i typed in TO it would still show me TOUR even tho I’m not done spelling it out

Comment: You want to find out if one string starts with another? Have you looked at the Swift [`String` interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html) to see if there are any functions related to that?

Comment: No i want to search in a list of stuff. I have it working so if TOUR is in the list it finds that but i want it to also give me a result if i typed in TO it would still show me TOUR even tho I’m not done spelling it out

Comment: Decomposition is the first part of problem solving. Do you know what the code in your post is doing? The critical line is `$0.subCategoryName == searchController.searchBar.text!`. This is testing whether a subcategory name *exactly matches* the search text (and it gets applied to every subcategory in order to filter the list to those that match). You just need to find an API that helps you change "*exactly matches*" to "starts with".

Comment: @rickster thats what i need the help with. I know its doing the exact match but how do i get it to search from letters. Any code examples?

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'rangeOfString()' method.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    self.filteredsub.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    filteredsub = subCatArray.filter{
        $0.subCategoryName.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text!) != nil
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You can also convert to lower case the strings, to make the search 'case insensitive'.

```
$0.subCategoryName.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) != nil
```